# Opening a custom port on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, port, firewall, iptables

I'm configuring a NAT instance that should redirect all incoming requests on port 2222 to port 22 of a server in a private subnet on my virtual private cloud, so I can connect with SSH straight to my private instance. I have opened port 2222 on the NAT Instance's security group and 22 on my private instance's security group, as well as added on

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

the following lines:

```
Port 22
Port 2222
```

nmap on NAT instance shows that port 2222 is open:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
2222/tcp open  EtherNet/IP-1
```

I also added this following iptables rule on my NAT instance, hence any packages that comes on port 2222 should be redirected to 10.0.2.18:22 (10.0.2.18 is the private instance IP):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.18:22
```

The problem is that I can't reach port 2222 of my NAT instance, if I try this:

```
ssh -p 2222 -i mykey.pem ec2-user@my_nat_ip
```

or this:

```
nc -zv my_nat_ip 2222
```

I get a connection time out.

Thanks in advance any help.

Comment: can you paste the Security group rule for your NAT instance?

Comment: In ssh_config just keep line Port 2222 remove the line Port 22 and check

Comment: Check my second comment did you try that?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/r1D9QtPW here's my security group details

Comment: I already tried to remove port 22 and left just port 2222 but it still does not work. I also get connection time out.

Comment: If you SSH into your NAT server, can you SSH from it into the private instance? Or does it timeout as well?

Comment: Yes, I can ssh from NAT to the private instance

Answer (score 1):

A few things for you to check out (assuming you have already ruled out Security Groups):

- Check if you haven't denied traffic on your Network ACLs (NACL).
- Check if the Route Table for your private subnet is sending traffic to the NAT instance.
- Check if you have disabled the `Source/Destination Check` on your NAT instance.

Also, you might want to enable VPC Flow Logs on your VPC to help you find where those packets might be getting dropped.

And then, another suggestion: you might want to consider an alternative to port forwarding, as this is basically exposing your instance in the private subnet to the dangerous internet. A common approach is to have what is commonly referred to as a *Bastion Host*. Or a *Jump Host*. Some people use a *NAT instance* for this purpose. A few ways to do this would include: (1) use SSH local port forwarding; (2) use SSH dynamic proxy; (3) use the `ProxyCommand` option on your SSH client. There are plenty of answered questions about all these subjects on StackOverflow and other StackExchange sites, you'll definitely find many ways to do it!

Comment: I'll verify this. The problem is that I need to have in some way access to the internet from my private subnet. I'm using a NAT instance because with it I can allow inbound (for ssh) and outbound traffic to get software updates. So in another scenario, for example, using a bastion host, I would need to configure at least a NAT gateway, hence I would can connect to internet from my private subnet. Do you consider this a good solution?